# Citing bullet points in block quotes forces the number to be 1

Tags: support, markdown

I wanted to quote a single (not the first) bullet point in a bulleted list from another site. I used the block quote function to indent the text and place it in a grey box to denote it as separate from the main text. I copied and pasted the quote including the number at the beginning e.g. "9. blah blah". However in an attempt to list bullet points in order the representation was show as "1. blah blah". When I went to edit the text, the original was still there i.e. "9" but readers would see "1.".

Am I just using the block-quote function incorrectly in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 5. in a pinch you can escape the point `.` to preserve the numbering

Markdown source:

```
>5\. in a pinch you can escape the point `.` to preserve the numbering
```

> 5. Now [you don't need to escape the point anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239121) to start a numbered list at an arbitrary number.

Markdown source:

```
>5. Now [you don't need to escape the point anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239121 "as announced here") to start a numbered list at an arbitrary number.
```

Comment: Well done. That seems to be it. Did you also edit my original post to include the "\"? When I went to add your suggested solution to the post it had already been done.

Comment: @Encaitar no it was Yannis. You can see who edited your post in the [revision history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/232101/revisions)

Comment: Thanks @Yannis.